# mDNS and Sockets for Chrome Extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Since Chrome Apps are being discontinued effective 2018, does anyone know if chrome.mdns and chrome.sockets API's are going to be made available for Chrome Extensions?

Answer (score 0):

If you check this [blog](https://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html) about the Chrome Apps, it only stated here that in early 2018, users on these platforms (Windows, Mac, and Linux) will no longer be able to load Chrome apps, but it will still be available in the CHROME OS. And it is not stated here the effect of it in the Chrome Extension.

So what can I suggest you is to check the [chrome.mdns](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/mdns) and [chrome.socket](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket) for the updates on this API.